# Send the same transaction from multiple accounts in remix in loop

Tags: solidity, remix

Is this possible to for example approve and send  the same transaction from multiple accounts in injected web3 connected (metamask) and accept only once? or do we need to switch accounts and each time accept each transaction in metmask?is it possible with injected web3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remix currently doesn't allow automatically looping through multiple accounts and sending the transaction from each one automatically.

Also MetaMask doesn't support approving a batch of transaction at once, and requires each transaction to be approved separately.

---

You could achieve the desired result in node.js for example:

```
const web3 = new Web3('<provider with multiple accounts>');

for (let account of web3.eth.getAccounts()) {
    contract.methods.foo().send({from: account});
}
```